# MySQL process exits after starting "Cannot open datafile for read-only '-/x.ibd' OS error: 203" (xampp control panel)

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to enable MySQL process set to port 3307 via XAMPP panel. The process fails to start and I resort to the log record

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 3 in a file operation.
2023-05-18 6:51:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
2023-05-18 6:51:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2023-05-18 6:51:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: '.\provisional_database\x.ibd' OS error: 203
2023-05-18 6:51:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-05-18 6:51:00 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-05-18 6:51:00 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``provisional_database`.`x``.
```

I have followed the documented url to find out how to fix the error: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
However the guide is to query and drop the orphaned intermediate tables, but I have no way to do this via SQL queries because I can't open the port. Is there a way to delete the orphaned tables manually through the directory manager? Or is something else preventing the process from starting correctly?

Comment: 3 in windows is ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND. Manually interacting with file is a sure why to break things further. What has changed? Did some paths move or a `datadir` configuration variable change?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have exactly the same problem, though natively, not from XAMP.